# jFieldId int not valid for an object

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Try to build my second jni android application and stuck at a point.

This is my basic example package

```
package com.example.angelica.myapplication;


public class SomeVars { 
    //load library

    public int aPrivate;

    public native void UpdateVars();
}
```

and my jni implementation

```
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_angelica_myapplication_SomeVars_UpdateVars(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    // TODO
    jclass  cls = getclass();  
    jfieldID  fid = getField("aPrivate");

    jint i = env->GetIntField(cls,fid);

    i = i + 100;
    env->SetIntField(cls, fid,i);
}
```

and my MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    SomeVars var = new SomeVars();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);

        var.aPrivate = 23;
        if (var.aPrivate == 23) {
            tv.setText("23");
        }else {
            tv.setText("Two Hunderd");
        }

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                var.UpdateVars();

                if (var.aPrivate == 23) {
                    tv.setText("23");
                }else {
                    tv.setText("Changed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Project build successfully, and is launched correctly. But when the button is clicked project abnormally stops. I tried to look at the logcat logs. but can't understand the reason behind the error. Posting the few lines of the logcat

```
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jfieldID int com.example.angelica.myapplication.SomeVars.aPrivate not valid for an object of class java.lang.Class<com.example.angelica.myapplication.SomeVars>
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to GetIntField
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from void com.example.angelica.myapplication.SomeVars.UpdateVars()
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x7449df60 self=0xa968b400
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | sysTid=3949 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xada11534
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=18 core=1 HZ=100
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | stack=0xbf5fe000-0xbf600000 stackSize=8MB
04-16 13:34:56.171 3949-3949/com.example.angelica.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

I am basically trying to achieve when button is clicked the value of aPrivate is updated and displayed in the textview. From my lookup it is clear that all error is in jni implementation.

**Update :**

I have tracked down error which is occuring in two locations in jni implementation

```
jint i = env->GetIntField(cls,fid);  //Error 1
env->SetIntField(cls, fid,200);      //Error 2
```

If i comment this two line no error is occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was bit mistake in Setting SetIntField it should be setting the field using instance.

```
env->SetIntField(cls, fid,200);      //Error 
env->SetIntField(instance, fid, 200); //SOLVED
```

Now every thing is working good

Comment: Can you please explain why would that cause an error?